# When/can I use JDK 7 with CloudBees Run@cloud?

Tags: java-7, cloudbees

Would like to be able to use JDK 7 with CloudBees Run@cloud.  JDK 7 already is supported on CloudBees Jenkins.

Don't think it's possible now, would like an ETA...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now do this by setting the "runtime" parameter:

```
bees app:deploy -Rjava_version=1.7 yourapp
```

The versions available currently are 1.6 (Java 6), 1.7 (Java 7) and 1.8 (Java 8)

You can read more about other options here https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container

Comment: We're also eagerly awaiting for this to happen! Any news on this?

Comment: It's Oct 1st, just checked docs and config and don't see any reference to JDK 7.  Will check again in two weeks.

Comment: Will - happy day - with the latest bees SDK you can use -Rjava_version=1.7 and you get java 1.7 ! (1.8 is also on there, I think to experiment with).

Comment: Is Java 7 also available in the EU run@cloud? At least the PaaS console there seems a bit outdated compared to the US...